# unable to connect internet dongle in fedora

Tags: linux, internet, fedora, dongle

I have installed fedora 16 Gnome. I have been using usb-dongle to connect to internet in windows. But when i inserted the same dongle in fedora it didn't show any device. What is the way i can connect to mobile internet using dongle in fedora ?

The main problem is that fedora is unable to detect the dongle.

*Model Number : MMX352G*

*Manufacturer : Micromax*

Comment: What dongle/device/ANYTHING?

Comment: @ Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams couldn't understand your comment

Comment: Devices have a manufacturer and a model number. Or they have some markings on them that identifies them. Or they have IDs that software can read. Or they have effects that can be seen in the system log. You have given NONE of those.

Comment: @ Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams please see the edit

Answer (score 1):

A [quick Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=micromax+mmx352g+linux) found http://hashprompt.blogspot.com/2011/05/micromax-mmx-352g-usb-3g-modem-with.html. Install `usb_modeswitch` and then configure NetworkManager after plugging it in.

Comment: I guess that is for ubuntu. Will the issue be the same in fedora

Comment: Did you bother reading the rest of my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `/etc/usb_modeswitch.d/`. Then create a new file with name `0421:0628` paste the following in this file then restart

```
########################################################
# Micromax MMX352G

DefaultVendor= 0x0421
DefaultProduct=0x060c

TargetVendor=  0x0421
TargetProduct= 0x060e

CheckSuccess=20

MessageContent="5553424312345678000000000000061b000000020000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

It is fedora 16 which is the latest one, so you just need to install `usb_modeswitch`, plug-in the data-card and configure your network manager, as ignacio said.
http://hashprompt.blogspot.com

Comment: Why are you linking an entire blog? If there is useful information in a blog entry, please link it directly instead of the entire blog. Additionally, if there are relevant instructions or information, you can link and describe what you're linking.